# Two separate circuits in one outlet box

Tags: wiring, receptacle

Putting in new outlet and discovered 2 circuits run thought it. One is for the outlet, the other is for the washing machine on the opposite wall behind it. The outlet has only one hot. It’s NOT switched.

Both circuits share the same common.
My question is, why would someone run a hot down a wall into a box then run it back up the wall, over and across and back down the wall behind?

I ended up getting zapped cuz I only expected one circuit in the box.

Comment: Sounds like you mean a Multi Wire Branch Circuit if the non-standard term "common" is meant to be Neutral. And you might have found out why current code (but not some earlier editions) requires handle-tied breakers for those.

Comment: Can you provide us a photo that clearly shows the back of the box in question please?

Comment: Stop calling it "common".  It's neutral. This misunderstanding is part of why you got zapped.  It's common on automobiles and electronics, but in AC power neutral is wired separately.  Every neutral serves 1  partner "hot" and is monogamous to that "hot".  (in some cases 2 partner hots, to which it is bigamous). **That circuits neutral NEVER serves any other hot wires**.  That's why it's neutral *and not common*.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, this is why I cut the main before doing work.  Panels are too full of surprises (even panels I built from scratch *and failed to check the neutral-ground bonding on*).

What you have there is called a "Multi-Wire Branch Circuit" aka MWBC aka shared neutral.  It is 1 circuit with multiple hots.   Why?

[image]

It's cheaper.  You run one /3 cable from the panel and get "2 circuits worth" of power out of 1 circuit. Or a house fire if you wire it wrong.  Or an electric handshake.

Now, *modern* code addresses these with several reforms.  First, you are required to place both hot wires on the same 2-pole breaker*.  This helps maintainers not get zapped, since they are forced to turn off *the entire* circuit.   It also helps with correct placement of the breakers: [North American electrical has 2 poles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMmUoZh3Hq4), and the two hot wires *need to be* on opposite poles to avoid overloading neutral.

Other than that, neutral in MWBCs must be pigtailed at each place both hots are present - *that's* so you can remove devices without having to interrupt neutral, which in case you haven't noticed, *can be hot* lol.

If you get those details right, there's nothing wrong with MWBCs, until you need to put GFCI or AFCI on them-- *oh wait, they have GFCIs and AFCIs for them as well now*.

Also, if you put them on generator transfer switches, you need to throw *the whole MWBC* and it must throw together - you can't have a possibility of one leg being on utility and one leg of generator.

Comment: Good point about the pigtails; I hadn't thought about that situation. Though with the tied breakers both circuits should be dead if you're working on either, I can see how maintaining the neutral path would qualify as additional safety in case someone mis-wired. Presumably also best practice generally if there's something else downstream of this box, in case neutral gets mismatched there. Which is a good reason always to pigtail rather than trying to use the outlet's other screw for passthrough. (Aha! moment.)